# using inappbrowser in index.html

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am creating a radio streaming app. I am using javascript file from my radio server to show 'now playing' and 'Recent tracks' widgets. I know that the javascript files from web server works only with inappbrowser plugin. And it works when i open the demo.html from index.html. i want to show all widgets in index.html and i dont wanna send users to another page to view radio details.

Is there any way to use inappbrowser plugin in index.html. Or any way to make external javascript work in index.html.

Comment: why does it only work in InAppBrowser? Could this be worked around with a suitable CSP or by whitelisting?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using phonegap build just add the required inappbrowser tag to your config.xml: